# Pass a container type as the typename of a template in c++

Tags: c++, templates, containers, std

I'm a beginner at templates in C++ and I would like to know if it's possible to pass a container to the typename of a template function, here is what I'm trying to do:

```
template <typename T>
int find_size(const T<int> t)
{
    return (t.size());
}

int main(void)
{
    std::array<int, 10> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        test[i] = i;
    }
    findsize(test);
}
```

When I'm compiling I get an error saying that T isn't a template.
Is it possible to pass the template of a container to the template of a function?

Comment: Should be `find_size(const T& t)` then `return t.size()`?

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? In your `find_size` `T` is once used as a type, once as a template and once as if it was an object

Comment: I corrected my mistake, basically I want my function to be able to take an abritary type of container

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With minimum changes to make it work, your code could be this:

```
#include <array>

template <typename T>
int find_size(const T& t)
{
    return (t.size());
}

int main(void)
{
    std::array<int, 10> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        test[i] = i;
    }
    find_size(test);
}
```

> basically I want my function to be able to take an abritary type of container

Thats exactly what the above does. It works for any container type `T` that has a `size()`.

---

If you actually want to parametrize `find_size` on a template rather than a type, then you can use a template template parameter:

```
#include <array>

template <template<class,std::size_t> class C>
int find_size(const C<int,10>& t)
{
    return (t.size());
}

int main(void)
{
    std::array<int, 10> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        test[i] = i;
    }
    find_size<std::array>(test);
}
```

However, using this is either more complicated than illustrated here, or of more limited use than the above: For the function parameter you need a type not just a template, and this `find_size` will only work with a template `C` that has 2 parameters, one type and one non-type parameter of type `size_t` (and I am actually not aware of any other container but `std::array` with that template parameters).

---

TL;DR: This is not a use case where a template template parameter is needed.

> Is it possible to pass the template of a container to the template of a function?

Yes, but you don't need it here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm still kinda confused with templates so I thought it would be more complicated to do what I was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your type to your templatized function. The compiler will check if the calls to this function are valid or not (i.e.: it will check if each call to your function is done with an object that has a `size()` method).`

I fixed your code, try if this works (untested)

```
template <typename T>
int find_size(const T &v)
{
    return int(v.size());
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        test[i] = i;
    }
    find_size(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void main` is not C++. Don't use it.

Comment: @AnoopRana my bad, I fixed it

Comment: Thanks it's working like I want, I was confused about how to use templates for my use case

Comment: @Orcepee just remember this: if you call a method/operator inside a templatized function, the template argument has to have a definition for that method/operator. In this case, you wanted to call `size`, so it will work as long as your template parameter has that method. If you were to call it with a `int myarray[20]`, you will have a compilation error.

Comment: Got it! templates are getting more clear in my mind now

Answer (score 0):

T is a type name, so calling .size() doesn't really make sense here.

Why are you trying to use templates if you want a parameter with a type?
You could type cast your return.

try

```
template <typename T>
int find_size(T a)
{
return (int) a.size();
}
```